# How to get unicode code point(s) representation of character/string in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, unicode, character, codepoint

As a generic solution, how can we get the unicode code point/s for a character or a string in Swift?

Consider the following:

```
let A: Character = "A"     // "\u{0041}"
let Á: Character = "Á"     // "\u{0041}\u{0301}"

let sparklingHeart = ""  // "\u{1F496}"
let SWIFT = "SWIFT"        // "\u{0053}\u{0057}\u{0049}\u{0046}\u{0054}"
```

If I am not mistaking, the desired function might return an array of strings, for instance:

```
extension Character {
    func getUnicodeCodePoints() -> [String] {
        //...
    }
}

A.getUnicodeCodePoints()
// the output should be: ["\u{0041}"]

Á.getUnicodeCodePoints()
// the output should be: ["\u{0041}", "\u{0301}"]

sparklingHeart.getUnicodeCodePoints()
// the output should be: ["\u{1F496}"]

SWIFT.getUnicodeCodePoints()
// the output should be: ["\u{0053}", "\u{0057}", "\u{0049}", "\u{0046}", "\u{0054}"]
```

Any more suggested elegant approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, the `unicodeScalars` property of a `String` returns a collection
of its unicode scalar values. (A [Unicode scalar value](http://unicode.org/glossary/#unicode_scalar_value) is any
Unicode code point except high-surrogate and low-surrogate code points.)

Example:

```
print(Array("Á".unicodeScalars))  // ["A", "\u{0301}"]
print(Array("".unicodeScalars)) // ["\u{0001F496}"]
```

Up to Swift 3 there is no way to access
the unicode scalar values of a `Character` directly, it has to be
converted to a `String` first (for the Swift 4 status, see below).

If you want to see all Unicode scalar values as hexadecimal numbers
then you can access the `value` property (which is a `UInt32` number)
and format it according to your needs.

Example (using the `U+NNNN` notation for Unicode values):

```
extension String {
    func getUnicodeCodePoints() -> [String] {
        return unicodeScalars.map { "U+" + String($0.value, radix: 16, uppercase: true) }
    }
}

extension Character {
    func getUnicodeCodePoints() -> [String] {
        return String(self).getUnicodeCodePoints()
    }
}


print("A".getUnicodeCodePoints())     // ["U+41"]
print("Á".getUnicodeCodePoints())     // ["U+41", "U+301"]
print("".getUnicodeCodePoints())    // ["U+1F496"]
print("SWIFT".getUnicodeCodePoints()) // ["U+53", "U+57", "U+49", "U+46", "U+54"]
print("".getUnicodeCodePoints())    // ["U+1F1EF", "U+1F1F4"]
```

**Update for Swift 4:**

As of  Swift 4, the `unicodeScalars` of a `Character` can be
accessed directly,
see [SE-0178 Add unicodeScalars property to Character](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0178-character-unicode-view.md). This makes the conversion to a `String` 
obsolete:

```
let c: Character = ""
print(Array(c.unicodeScalars)) // ["\u{0001F1EF}", "\u{0001F1F4}"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please note the output that I got of `print(Array("Á".unicodeScalars))` was `["\u{00C1}"]` but *not* `["A", "\u{0301}"]`, similar to this case, I tried: `print(Array("é".unicodeScalars))` and the output was `["\u{00E9}"]` but not `["u", "e\u{0301}"]`; I know it should be ok when comparing, they should be equals, but I wonder what's the reason of this...

Comment: @AhmadF: That's because there is a "precomposed" and a "decomposed" representation of characters with combining diacritical marks. Try `"Á".precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.getUnicodeCodePoints()` and `"Á".decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.getUnicodeCodePoints()`